# How to create a single shared object (C language) for testing and production environment in R

Tags: c, r, testing, shared-libraries, extern

I am building a shared object (`.so`) file built from C, to be used from R. I am having problems linking/compiling the object with all the source codes, test codes and header files.

This `.so` file will be loaded using `dyn.load()` in R and the corresponding functions called.

This single `so` file will be used

- by `testthat` package in R to test the functions
- to create a demo script for the package
- expose all the functions in the package for a typical user

The `CMainFile.c` file has a set of global variables (random number generator specifics) which can be accessed by `CMainFile.c` (when the main functions are called by the user from R) and by `testfile.c` (when testing functions are called in the testing phase by the user from R).

How do I create the shared object which allows functions `test_get_and_add` (in testfile) and `same_as_test_get_and_add` (in CMainfile) to be called from R.

I also DO NOT want two separate shared objects (one for testing and one for use by an user) (this I have tried and works).

I am providing test files here:

file1.h

```
void myaddfunc(double *x, double *y, double *s);
```

file2.h

```
void printadd(double *x, double *y, double *s);
```

globalvars.h

```
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_machine.h>
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_cdf.h>
extern const gsl_rng *gBaseRand;       // global rand number generator
extern unsigned long randSeed;
extern const double lowest_double;
extern const double highest_double;
extern FILE *fp;
```

CMainFile.h

```
void set_pseudo_RNG(void);
void get_and_add(double *x, double *s);
```

file1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>    
void myaddfunc(double *x, double *y, double *s){
    *s = *x + *y;
}
```

file2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "globalvars.h"    
void printadd(double *x, double *y, double *s){
    fprintf(fp, "\n Add %f and %f to get: %f. \n", *x, *y, *s);
}
```

CMainFile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_machine.h>
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_randist.h>
#include </usr/local/include/gsl/gsl_cdf.h>

#include "globalvars.h"
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

// random number generation set up
const gsl_rng *gBaseRand;       // global rand number generator
unsigned long randSeed;
const double lowest_double = -GSL_DBL_MAX;
const double highest_double = GSL_DBL_MAX;
FILE *fp = NULL;

// set the global pseudo random number generator
void set_pseudo_RNG(void){

    /* specifying to use Mersenne twister as the uniform PRNG */
    gBaseRand = gsl_rng_alloc(gsl_rng_mt19937);
    srand(time(NULL));                    /* initialization for rand() */
    randSeed = rand();                    /* returns a non-negative integer */
    gsl_rng_set(gBaseRand, randSeed);     /* seed the PRNG */
}

void same_as_test_get_and_add(double *x, double *s){
    set_pseudo_RNG();
    get_and_add(x, s);
}

// takes a numeric input x
// generates random y from normal distribution
// calls a function to add x & y. prints sum.
// RNG has to be set up before calling this function
void get_and_add(double *x, double *s){        
    double *y;
    *y = gsl_ran_ugaussian(gBaseRand);
    myaddfunc(x, y, s);    
    printadd(x, y, s);
}
```

testfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "globalvars.h"
#include "CMainFile.h"

void test_get_and_add(double *x, double *s){
    set_pseudo_RNG();
    get_and_add(x, s);
}
```

This compiles:

```
R CMD SHLIB CMainFile.c testfile.c file1.c file2.c -lgsl -lgslcblas
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/sw/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c CMainFile.c -o CMainFile.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/sw/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c testfile.c -o testfile.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/sw/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c file1.c -o file1.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/sw/include -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2  -c file2.c -o file2.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/sw/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o CMainFile.so CMainFile.o testfile.o file1.o file2.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -F/usr/local/R.framework/.. -framework R -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

but does not run in R:

```
x = vector("numeric", 1)
s = vector("numeric", 1)
dyn.load("CMainFile.so")
.C("test_get_and_add:, as.double(x), as.double(s)

 *** caught illegal operation ***
address 0x10484dcd2, cause 'illegal opcode'

Traceback:
 1: .C("test_get_and_add", as.double(x), as.double(s))

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Same thing happens with `same_as_test_get_and_add`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's a lot of information out there on interfacing with C from R that you might find useful:

1. Why not just make a package? This way people can just install and load your package rather than `dyn.load`-ing shared objects.
2. The `.Call` interface is preferred to the `.C` interface; see [Section 5](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#System-and-foreign-language-interfaces) of the R-exts manual.
3. Your life is made easier if you use [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) to operate on R objects in C++ code.

Also, a nitpick: you should use portable include paths; `<gsl/*>` is preferred to `</usr/local/gsl/*>`.

That said, after compiling and trying to run your code in `R -d gdb`, I see

```
[New Thread 0x170b of process 3829]
[New Thread 0x1803 of process 3829]
[New Thread 0x1903 of process 3829]
```

R itself is single threaded, and I wouldn't be surprised if the error is a result of these threads being spawned, trying to modify R objects, and then breaking everything. Although I'm not sure where exactly these threads are being spawned as I am not so familiar with GSL.

So,

1. Why not just use the R random number generator? You can set the type if you'd like: see `?RNG`. I'm sure there are ways to handle it in C as well.
2. Make a package, don't just build and distribute shared objects. See the [package development](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/#package-development) guide by Hadley Wickham.
3. Check out [RcppGSL](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.gsl.html).